# Superimpose an image on each bubble in D3 bubble chart

Tags: d3.js, bubble-chart

I am currently working on a motion bubble chart in D3: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/:

[image]

I want to superimpose an image on each of the bubble, so I added the code:

```
var dot = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
    .selectAll(".dot")
    .data(interpolateData(formatDate(format, minDate)))
   .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .style("fill","none")
    .call(position)
    .sort(order);

dot.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16)
.call(position);
```

But it won't work. Very appreciate on any help.